# How to initialize a combo value in viewController init() without firing its change event

Tags: extjs

I have a Sencha Fiddle that describes the problem:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/13ol

I want to initialize the combo, but avoid firing its change event (until after init() is complete).  The value for the combo is first available in the viewController init() method.

Comment: You could either set a flag before setting the value. Or call suspendEvents on the combo and then resume after.

Answer (score 0):

Use `value` config to create combobox with an initial value.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.TestViewControler', {
    ...
    init: function() {
        // Do something
        var newValue = 'Week'; // Get new value
        this.getView().addCombo(newValue);
    }
    ...
});

Ext.define('MyApp.view.TestView', {
    ...
    addCombo: function(value) {
        this.add({
            xtype: 'combo',
            reference: 'MyCombo',
            editable: false,
            hidden: false,
            fieldLabel: 'My Combo',
            bind: {
                store: '{comboStore}'
            },
            displayField: 'name',
            valueField: 'key',
            listeners: {
                change: 'onMyComboChange'
            },
            value: value
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: If you have any reason to call 'init' , please tell me

Comment: I do.  As stated in the problem, the value is not available until init().  I don't think the reasons for that are relevant.

Comment: I updated my answer. I think you should add combobox after you got the initial value.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you can defer it until after init function, but you can at least defer it until directly before init function ends:

```
init: function() {
    var combo = this.lookupReference('MyCombo');
    combo.suspendEvent("change");
    combo.setValue('Week');
    // do everything else you want to do in init.
    combo.resumeEvent("change");
}
```

I have tested in your fiddle that this code:

```
init: function() {
    var combo = this.lookupReference('MyCombo');
    combo.suspendEvent("change");
    combo.setValue('Week');
    console.log('testfirst');
    combo.resumeEvent("change");
},

onMyComboChange: function() {
    console.log('testsecond')
    // Need to avoid firing this method during init
}
```

produces this console.log:

```
run?_dc=1452632485198:60 testfirst
run?_dc=1452632485198:65 testsecond
```

Comment: I might edit my question to be more clear.  I need to set the value of the combo in init() *without triggering onMyComboChange* at all.